# i trying to add a bind variable ? in the where to my mysql statement

Tags: php, mysql, json, bind

I have three sets of code below and the first is the current code I am using in my android/iphone app. The php code in the first reads a database and returns a json encode array. All works good. what i need to do is use a prepare with bind variable and return the same json array as before except using a bind ? variable to limit the rows. the second was my attempt to use bind variable and it return the data but not as a json array as the first. 
third was my last try but it return an array full of true.

basically what is need to allow the first to use bind and return the same json data.

thanks

error_log("\n\n #######################     1      ################################" ,3,"master.log");

```
    $sqlvalue1 = "A";

    if ($what_to_do == "select_push_groups")
    {
        $empty=array();

        $sql = "select email from users ";

        error_log("\n select_sql: " . $sql ,3,"master.log");

        if ($stmt_s = mysqli_prepare($conn, $sql))
        {
        //mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt_s, 's',$sqlvalue1);
                mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt_s);
                mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt_s);
        }
        else
        {
                error_log("\n select prepare error: " .  mysqli_errno($conn) . "-" . mysqli_error($conn)  ,3,"android_post_array.log");
                $resultArray = array(array("success" => "NO", "message" => mysqli_errno($conn) . " " . mysqli_error($conn) , "count" => 0));
                echo json_encode(array('success'=>$resultArray));
                //exit;
        }

        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        if (mysqli_num_rows($result) == 0)
        {
            //$resultArray = array(array("success" => "YES", "message" => "empty", "count" => 0));
            //echo json_encode(array('success'=>$resultArray));
            echo json_encode(array('result'=>$empty));
        }
        if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
        {
            $resultArray = array();
            $tempArray = array();

            while($row = $result->fetch_object())
            {
                $tempArray = $row;
                //echo $row->id;
                array_push($resultArray, $tempArray);
                //error_log("\n select tempArray : " . print_R($tempArray,TRUE) ,3,"master.log");
            }
            error_log("\n select resultArray : " . print_R($resultArray,TRUE) ,3,"master.log");
            error_log("\n select json_encode : " . json_encode($resultArray) ,3,"master.log");

            //echo json_encode($resultArray);
            //echo json_encode(array('result'=>$resultArray));
        }
        //mysqli_close($conn);
        //exit;
    }



    error_log("\n\n #######################     2      ################################" ,3,"master.log");





if ($what_to_do == "select_push_groups")
{

    $cnt = "";
    $empty=array();

        $sqlvalue1 = "8";

    $sql = "select
        id as column1, 
        code as column2
        from push_groups where id > ? ";

    if ($stmt_sql = mysqli_prepare($conn, $sql))
    {
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt_sql, 's',$sqlvalue1);
        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt_sql);
        mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt_sql);

        $cnt = mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt_sql);
        if ($cnt == 0)
            {
            error_log("\n cnt=0 : " . $cnt ,3,"master.log");
                    echo json_encode(array('result'=>$empty));
            }
        if ($cnt > 0)
            {
            error_log("\n cnt>0 : " . $cnt ,3,"master.log");            
            mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt_sql, $id, $code);
            while (mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt_sql))
            {
                error_log("\n cnt>0 : " . $id . " " . $code ,3,"master.log");
            }
            }
    }
        else
        {
                error_log("\n select prepare error: " .  mysqli_errno($conn) . "-" . mysqli_error($conn)  ,3,"master.log");
                $resultArray = array(array("success" => "NO", "message" => mysqli_errno($conn) . " " . mysqli_error($conn) , "count" => 0));
                echo json_encode(array('success'=>$resultArray));
                exit;
        }

}



    error_log("\n\n #######################    3      ################################" ,3,"master.log");





if ($what_to_do == "select_push_groups")
{

    $cnt = "";
    $empty=array();

        $sqlvalue1 = "8";

    $sql = "select
        id as column1, 
        code as column2
        from push_groups where id > ? ";

    if ($stmt_sql = mysqli_prepare($conn, $sql))
    {
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt_sql, 's',$sqlvalue1);
        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt_sql);
        mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt_sql);

        $cnt = mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt_sql);
        if ($cnt == 0)
            {
            error_log("\n cnt=0 : " . $cnt ,3,"master.log");
                    echo json_encode(array('result'=>$empty));
            }
        if ($cnt > 0)
            {
            error_log("\n cnt>0 : " . $cnt ,3,"master.log");                    
            $resultArray = array();
                    $tempArray = array();

                    while($row = mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt_sql))
                    {
                        $tempArray = $row;
                        //echo $row->id;
                //error_log("\n row->id : " . $row->id ,3,"master.log");
                        array_push($resultArray, $tempArray);
                        error_log("\n select tempArray : " . print_R($tempArray,TRUE) ,3,"master.log");
                    }
                    error_log("\n select resultArray : " . print_R($resultArray,TRUE) ,3,"master.log");
                    error_log("\n select json_encode : " . json_encode($resultArray) ,3,"master.log");

                    //echo json_encode($resultArray);
                    echo json_encode(array('result'=>$resultArray));
            }
            mysqli_close($conn);
            exit;
    }
        else
        {
                error_log("\n select prepare error: " .  mysqli_errno($conn) . "-" . mysqli_error($conn)  ,3,"master.log");
                $resultArray = array(array("success" => "NO", "message" => mysqli_errno($conn) . " " . mysqli_error($conn) , "count" => 0));
                echo json_encode(array('success'=>$resultArray));
                exit;
        }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

`mysqli_stmt_fetch` returns a boolean. And that function is only used after `mysqli_stmt_bind_result`, as code is doing in part `### 2 ###`.

In part `### 3 ###`, we don't see a call to `mysqli_stmt_bind_result`.

We can use a prepared statement and supply bind parameters to the statement, without binding the result.  Just use `fetch_array` to return an associative array.

```
$sqlvalue1 = "8";

if ($what_to_do == "select_push_groups")
{
    $resultArray = array();
    $sql = "select id as column1, code as column2 from push_groups where id > ? ";
    if ($stmt_sql = mysqli_prepare($conn, $sql))
    {
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt_sql, 's', $sqlvalue1);
        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt_sql);
        mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt_sql);
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($stmt_sql,MYSQLI_ASSOC))
        {
            $resultArray[] = $row;
        }
        echo json_encode(array('result'=>$resultArray));
        mysqli_stmt_free_result($stmt_sql);
        mysqli_close($conn);
        exit;
    }
    else
    {
        error_log("\n select prepare error: " .  mysqli_errno($conn) . "-" . mysqli_error($conn)  ,3,"master.log");
        $resultArray = array(array("success" => "NO", "message" => mysqli_errno($conn) . " " . mysqli_error($conn) , "count" => 0));
        echo json_encode(array('success'=>$resultArray));
        mysqli_close($conn);
        exit;
    }
}
```

If I thought I was having issues with the bind parameter, I would get it working without the `mysql_stmt_bind_param`; for testing, supply a literal in place of the question mark in the SQL text, and comment out the call to the bind_param.

I'd get that working and tested, then I'd go back and add the placeholder `?` in the SQL text, and add the bind_param.

Comment: I need to get the number of rows before running the while logic, because i return an empty array if now rows found due to bind

Comment: **`array('result'=>$resultArray)`** will return the exact same thing as **`array('result'=>$emtpy)`** when no rows are fetched, since `$resulttArray` is initialized to an empty array. (The `$empty` array declaration is unnecessary.) I'm not seeing any need for special handling of  a "no rows returned" condition.

Answer (score -1):

mySQL will not allow you to use a bound variable in a LIMIT.

You should create a stored procedure and pass the "limit amount" in this way.

Comment: i know that, i want to "selectively" limit (not the keyword limit. using a bind ? variable in set 1 and return a json array.

Comment: This answer is not very helpful.  OP query does not include the `LIMIT` keyword, the OP query is using a bind placeholder in the `WHERE` clause.